# To match a word from a pool of sentences using Python

Tags: python, string, string-matching

I have two different files File "Sentence" contains a pool of sentences, please find the snapshot below.
[Sentence Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oG9WD.jpg)

File "Word" contians pool of words, please find the snapshot below.

[Word file snap shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkvMX.jpg)

I want to map words from word file to sentence file if any word match with the sentence, I want the result in form of sentence and matched word

for example:
Sentence                         Match Words
Linux and open stack is great    Linux Open stack

Please find my code below, when I am trying to extract the result in to csv, its showing error.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

sentence_xlsx = pd.ExcelFile('C:\Python\Seema\Sentence.xlsx')
sentence_all = sentence_xlsx.parse('Sheet1')
#print(sentence_all)
word_xlsx = pd.ExcelFile('C:\Python\Seema\Word.xlsx')
word_all = word_xlsx.parse('Sheet1')            


for sentence in sentence_all['Article']:
    sentences = sentence.lower()

    for word in sentences.split():
        if word in ('linux','openstack'):
            result = word,sentence

results = open('C:\Python\Seema\result.csv', 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(results, dialect='excel')
writer.writerows(result)
results.close()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Word_Finder2.py", line 25, in <module>
    results = open('C:\Python\Seema\result.csv', 'wb')
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('wb') or filename: 'C:\\Python\\Seema\result.c
sv'
```

Comment: Please add the full traceback of the error

Comment: @Moses Koledoye : I have added the traceback error

Comment: Try opening with `'w'` mode instead. You may still get another error, as `writerows` works with a list of rows, and not just any iterable

Comment: Yes you are right, I am still getting error, what can be the best possible way to extract. As I am beginner in python.

Comment: Please indicate the new error also

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Word_Finder2.py", line 18, in <module>
    results = open('C:\Python\Seema\result.csv', 'w')
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('w') or filename: 'C:\\Python\\Seema\result.cs
v'

Comment: Your windows paths need to be raw literals: `r'C:\Python\Seema\result.csv'`

Comment: @georg I should have noticed `'\r'` was being treated as a carriage return without raw. Good eye

Comment: thank you georg, but still I am not getting the desired result. Is there anything wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `'\result.csv'` part of your path has its `'\r'` being read as a carriage return character. To fix this, append a leading `r` to the path to make it a raw string literal (credit @georg).

---

Then to use `writerows`, the result from all the iterations should be accumulated into a list and not just the last result.

```
result = [] # create list to hold result from each iteration
for sentence in sentence_all['Article']:
    sentences = sentence.lower()

    for word in sentences.split():
        if word in ('linux','openstack'):
            # append result of iteration to result
            result.append([sentence, word])
            #|<- creates list of rows suitable for 'writerows'

results = open(r'C:\Python\Seema\result.csv', 'wb')
#              ^ prevents \r... from being read as a special character
writer = csv.writer(results, dialect='excel')
writer.writerows(result)
results.close()
```

Comment: Moses I did this, but still, I am not getting the desired result.

Comment: What is the desired result?

Comment: I want  the sentence in one column and the matched word  in the second column

Comment: Does switching the order of `sentence` and `word` like I've done fix it?

Comment: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 5
0: ordinal not in range(128) I am getting this error

Comment: Try replacing the append line with `result.append([sentence.encode('ascii', 'ignore'), word.encode('ascii', 'ignore')])`

Comment: Thank You Moses, Can you explain why you use [ ] in result.append([sentence, word])

Comment: How can I add one or more words that are matched with the same sentence?

Comment: Because [`writerows`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows) takes a list of rows. `[]` creates the list and `append` adds a new row to the list

Comment: That would require checking multiple `words` before appending the row to the result. Hint: keep all the words found in a sentence in a list then append the words and sentence at the same time to the list

Comment: Thank You! Moses once again